# How do I fix that the number of attachments increases in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

In an endless while loop I want to send a mail with an attachment every 60 seconds. The attachment is a file that contains data of a measuring device. That means data is always changing. The code works fine but every time it sends the email it increases the number of attachments. That means when it sends the first mail it contains one attachment, when after 60 seconds it sends the second mail it contains the attachment twice, then after 60 seconds it contains the attachment three times and so on. It should have only one attachment. What do I wrong?

```
txt = MIMEText('Die heutigen Messdaten')
msg.attach(txt)

curr_time = time.time()
next_time = curr_time + 10
while True:
    if (next_time >= curr_time):
        curr_time = time.time()
        print("do nothing")
    else:
        s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
        s.login(email_user, email_pass)
        next_time = next_time + 60
        curr_time = time.time()
        print(next_time)
        print(curr_time)
        file_dir = '/home/pi/Projekte/Test1/'
        file_name = 'Stromzaehler18.txt'
        filename = file_dir + file_name
        #filename = '/home/pi/Projekte/Test1/Stromzaehler18.txt'
        fo18=open(filename,'rb')
        attach =
        email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fo18.read(),
       _subtype="pdf")
        fo18.close()
        attach.add_header('Content-
        Disposition','attachment',filename=file_name)
        msg.attach(attach)
        s.send_message(msg)
        s.quit()
print("Finished!")
s.quit()
```

Number of attachments increases every 60 seconds (else …).
Number of attachments should always be 1.

Comment: Try

`del attach`

In while loop after sending mail.

Unsetting variable might help you.

Comment: Thanx for the quick answer. I was looking for something like del attach but I didn't find it. Can you please explain a bit more in detail. Thank you

Comment: I was asuming that you are using python..   Just unset the attach variable before next iteration.

Comment: Resolved. I just "del msg" after I sent the message msg an then create a new message msg at the end of the loop.